# How to quote/escape a field name in AQL for arangodb?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I cannot find where to quote a field name that has a space in it, for example when doing

```
FILTER s._key = a.`Supplier Id`
```

The above, sql-style quote doesn't work, neither does array access. What's the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out now, I got bitten by SQL and forgot that equality comparison is made with `==` in AQL. Then the array access worked, so the way to use field names with spaces is this:

```
FILTER s._key == a['Supplier Id']
```

If the field is without spaces but has some special characters, it works to use backtick instead of array access:

```
FILTER s._key == a.`ÅterförsäljareId`
```

**Edit:** Another option is to use bind variables:

```
FILTER s._key == a.@field

// Passing this to the API as bind variables:
{
    "field": "Supplier Id"
}
```

Comment: Another (maybe better) solution could be to [use bind variables](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/Invoke.html) in such a case. Can you mark your own answer as accepted?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know bind variables could also be used for key names. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Field name can be escaped with backticks: FILTER p.`one-two`: [AQL: How to specify a collection that has a dash in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70707021/aql-how-to-specify-a-collection-that-has-a-dash-in-the-name)

Leaving this here because the marked solution does not per se answer the question of the title.