# AQL: How to specify a collection that has a dash in the name?

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection called `one-two` and I would like to list a few of the documents in the collection:

```
FOR v IN one-two
    RETURN v
```

But I get the following error:
`Query: AQL: collection or view not found: one (while parsing)`

**How do I specify the collection with a `-` in the name?**

I've tried the usual options, `'`, `"` and camelCasing it `oneTwo` but they all fail.
The ArangoDB documentation [Collection and View Names](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-naming-conventions-collection-and-view-names.html) clearly states that a dash (-) is permitted.

[image: Screenshot showing the error]

[image: Screenshot showing the collection]

Comment: Perhaps hints in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804928/how-to-quote-escape-a-field-name-in-aql-for-arangodb

Comment: Yes, you are right. This should have been made clear in the collection naming page that Dash (-) will need escaping..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normal REST requests operating on such a collection no escaping is needed.

However, in AQL a dash (-) can also be interpreted as a minus operator. That's why in a query, a name with a dash has to be put into backticks: `` `one-two` ``

But since this is only relevant for AQL, this information can be found in the [AQL Syntax documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/fundamentals-syntax.html), not in the documentation about collection names that you referenced.